# php insert values from one array into another

Tags: php, arrays

I got 2 following arrays:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
array(2) {
["id"]=> 5
["moreinfo"]=> 'moreinfo'
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
["id"]=>10,
["moreinfo"]=> 'moreinfo'

}
[2]=>
array(2) {
["id"]=>15
["moreinfo"]=> 'moreinfo'
} ... and so forth
```

and the second one:

```
array(3) {
[5] => "Mike"
[10]=> "Bob"
[15]=> "Alice" //here keys are user ids from the first array
```

I need to merge them in order to add the field name to the first array in order to get the following:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
["id"]=> 5,
["name"]=> Mike,
["moreinfo"]=> 'moreinfo'
}
[1]=>
array(3) {
["id"]=>10,
["name"]=> Bob,
["moreinfo"]=> 'moreinfo'

}
[2]=>
array(3) {
["id"]=>15,
["name"]=> Alice,
["moreinfo"]=> 'moreinfo'
}
```

I tried to use array_merge but it did not produce the desired result. Also I used foreach but it also inserted only 1 name at the end of the array. Any ideas how to fix that?
Thank you.

**UPD** My foreach try:

```
foreach($arr1 as $k => $v) {
            $arr1['name'] = $arr2[$v['id']];
        }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried with foreach and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy, go through each element of the first array and look for the name in second array by `ID` from first array.

So your code might look something like this,

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$element) {
   $element['name'] = $array2[$element['id']];
   $array[$key]=$element; //It's necessary to update the element.
}
```

In above case `$array` is a first array, and `$array2` is the second array having names by `id` key.

Comment: This worked, but are there any ideas how to insert a 'name' key between 'id' and 'moreinfo' keys? Thank you

Comment: Order doesn't matter in case of the associative array. Don't worry about that so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming two arrays are `$array1` and `$array2` respectively, you need to add a new key value pair for 'name' in `$array1` along with pre-existing records.

```
foreach ($array1 as &$arr) {
   /* $arr['id'] stores 5, 10, 15... So, that implies $array2[5] i.e Mike, $array2[10] i.e Bob and so on. */
   $arr['name'] = $array2[$arr['id']]; 
}
```

Comment: It updates only one item from the array. Also I tried with & but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array1 as $key=>$arr) {
    $array1[$key]['name'] = $array2[$arr['id']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you:

```
$arr1 = array(
  array("id"=>5,"moreinfo"=>"moreinfo"),
  array("id"=>10,"moreinfo"=>"moreinfo"),
  array("id"=>15,"moreinfo"=>"moreinfo")
);
$arr2 = array(5=>"mike",10=>"Bob",15=>"Alice");
//
$result = array_map(function($elm)use($arr2){
    $elm['name'] = $arr2[$elm["id"]];
    return array("id"=>$elm["id"],"name"=>$elm["name"],"moreinfo"=>$elm["moreinfo"]);
},$arr1);

var_dump($result);
```

result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 5
      'name' => string 'mike' (length=4)
      'moreinfo' => string 'moreinfo' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 10
      'name' => string 'Bob' (length=3)
      'moreinfo' => string 'moreinfo' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 15
      'name' => string 'Alice' (length=5)
      'moreinfo' => string 'moreinfo' (length=8)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the variant how to save an order